# keyboard tab navigation through 3 level dropdown navigation using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a 3 level sub navigation menus. I just want to navigate all the 3 levels using keyboard tab key only.
i have tried the following code, but no luck

```
$('nav').on('focus', 'a.nav-links', function() {   
    $(this).closest('li.nav-item').addClass('menu-active');
  }).on('blur', 'a.nav-links', function() {
    $(this).closest('li.nav-item').removeClass('menu-active');
  });
```

> [example code](https://codepen.io/RayM/pen/JCtij)
>   expecting like these menu with 2 sub level dropdowns.
>
> need to navigate through tab key only.

Appreciate your help and provide me a working example

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.

```
//i cleaned the code to make it as simple as possible
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5aa3cpyg/21/

i dealt with jQuery to accomplish it fast, you can try to apply the same condition with css pseudo-selectors or run with js.
It's totally usable with a keyboard using the tab key.

Hope it helps